# Will this SQL Condition Exclude NULL Values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE amount > -9.99 * power(10,125)
```

Will this query help me exclude the NULL and zero amount from table?
On executing its not excluding null and zero.

We can be done using:

```
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE amount > 0 AND amount IS NOT NULL
```

CAN I DO THIS WITH:

```
amount > -9.99 * power(10,125)
```

Comment: did u try it yourself ? If yes, please post the resutl/error. If No, please do it yourself first.

Comment: `where amount > 0` already excludes NULLs and zero. This is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate condition for `NOT NULL` values.It should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM x
WHERE amount IS NOT NULL AND amount > 0
```

Comment: Sorry it works,i need solution for  amount > -9.99 * power(10,125)

Comment: Your second condition causes an `Arithmetic overflow error`.

Comment: @OpenJDK just add these conditions in your where statement : "  (amount > -9.99 * power(10,125)) AND (amount<>0) AND (amount IS NOT NULL)  "

Comment: please can you explain use of amount > -9.99 * power(10,125)

Comment: @OpenJDK these are the conditions you required right? amount should not be equal zero , should not be NULL and greater than -9.99*(10*10*10......125 times)?